# Power supply of LOGO 12/24RC PLC from SIEMENS

Tags: power-supply

I bought `LOGO 12/24RC` PLC from SIEMENS, and I didn't try it yet because I am worry about the required voltage needed to switch it on. I tried to see the data sheet but I confused with lots of data. If any one has any idea I will be thankful.
[Here](http://siemens.5130cn.com/images/Article/Technical/0900766b805c2bc6.pdf) is the data sheet for LOGO 12/24RC

Comment: I hate to say it, but if you can't figure out what power is needed you will probably have a hard time doing anything else. Also plc programming is only remotely on-topic here. But for us to help, we will need you to provide us with more info, like links to the datasheet.

Comment: @Kellenjb: Thanks for the respones, I put the data sheet link. Where you suggest the suitable place of my question?

Comment: Read Appendix A. Permissable Voltage Range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Appendix A of the data sheet you have all the information you need:

[image]

So you can run the LOGO 12/24 from anything between 10.8V and 28.8V